# rotated div with overflow: scroll doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

The goal is to have a rectangular div that rotates to show content on hover. This content can overflow the div vertically, so there must be a way to scroll.
It works fine in FF, but in Chrome the scrollbar will be shown but won't be functional (as if the content had no overflow).

[minimal fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgray001/pso4mkze/22/)

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('card-wrapper');
const rotater = document.getElementById('card-rotater');

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  rotater.setAttribute('style', 'transform: rotateX(90deg);');
});

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  rotater.setAttribute('style', 'transform: rotateX(0deg);');
});
```

```css
#card-wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  perspective: 500px;
  width: 200px;
}

#card-rotater {
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#card {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(0.9) translateZ(50px);
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="card-wrapper">
  <div id="card-rotater">
    <div id="card">
      <div id="content">
        line1<br>
        line2<br>
        line3<br>
        line4<br>
        line5<br>
        line6<br>
        line7<br>
        line8<br>
        line10
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does setting the `overflow: auto;` to the `#card` solve the problem?

Comment: I feel dumb now since I thought I had tried that, but it looks like it does. Ha!
I'm still wondering what causes the discrepancy between FF and Chrome though if anyone has insight.

Comment: Another reason I'd rather have the scrollbar on the wrapper is there's some weirdness for touch scrolling if the scrollbar is on the child. I can work around it, but it is far from ideal.

Comment: Can you bring an example of the effect you are trying to achieve?